# Code First generated database strange behavior

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have two entities `Permission` and `PermissionDependency` , each `Permission` has many `PermissionDependency` .

for example "Permission1" depends on "Permission2" user can't get "Permission1" without having "Permission2".

Here are two entites code :

**`Permission`**

```
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(150)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PermissionDependency> Dependencies { get; set; }
```

**`PermissionDependency`**

```
    [Key, Column(Order = 0), ForeignKey("Permission")]
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }

    public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }

    public virtual Permission Parent { get; set; }
```

**Problem:**

I expected that table `PermissionDependency` will be have 2 Foreign keys `PermissionId` and `ParentId` and `IsRequired` , but the Generated table has extra column named `Permission_Id` which is the foreign key id of the `Permission` property.

**Edit:**
in `PermissionDependency` `PermissionId` and `ParentId` must have `key` annotation because they are a "composite key"

here is the generated table :

[image: PermissionDependency]

why Code first want to create the `Permission_Id` as Nullable column ?

what is wrong with this code to generate this strange behavior ??

---

**Edit2:**

I want to implement parents-child relationship between permissions , every permission may have more than one parent , how to implement this logic ?

Comment: Do you adding 2 relationships within those two tables?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure if you use the following code, it should generate the right keys and foreign keys:

```
public class Permission
{
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(150)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<PermissionDependency> Dependencies { get; set; }
}

public class PermissionDependency
{
    public int PermissionDependencyId { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool IsRequired { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but how will `PermissionDependency` know it must have 2 foreign keys to `Permission` table 

a permission may have a parent permission

Comment: Why do you have 2 foreign keys to the same table? If you look at the db that is generated from the model - it creates a FK because of the Dependencies property in Permission. Have a look at the db that is produced by the model I described. However, if you are talking about Permission having a parent Permission then that sounds more like a circular relationship within Permission table.

Comment: Yes I need a circular relationship within Permission table but every permission may have more than one parent , how to handle this structure ?

Answer (score 0):

In Normally you do not want to specify the foreign key Annotation if you user the table name as the field name, EF will automatically knows that is a foreign key to the related Table.An also the Key anotation also no need to add because of the same functionalities

So you have to do that like this.

**in Permission Class**

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Required, StringLength(150)]
public string Title { get; set; }

public virtual List<PermissionDependency> Dependencies { get; set; }
```

**In Permission Dependency Class**

```
public int PermissionId { get; set; }

public int ParentId { get; set; }

[DefaultValue(true)]
public bool IsRequired { get; set; }

public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
```

This will automatically do it for you. If success leave a comment.

Comment: in `PermissionDependency` I must add `key` annotation  on `PermissionId` and `ParentId` because they are a composite key

Comment: I think this is not logical. why do you add 2 relations with permission? why do you think like this.If one key is foreign key then why use another one? why use this. "public virtual Permission Parent { get; set; }".  I can't understand your logic. explain then I can help you.

Comment: please check Edit2 above

Comment: So one to many relation ship with permission and Permission Dependency  table, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It might be late for the OP but I had a similar issue which I fixed by overriding the OnModelCreating method in my DbContext.

In your case, I think something like the following would do the trick:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

   modelBuilder.Entity<PermissionDependency>()
               .HasRequired(d => d.Permission)
               .WithMany(o => o.Dependencies);
}
```

I came to this solution after reading [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx).